# how push query to bson.M{} with variable in golang

Tags: go

i have basic code such as:

```
query := {"number": bson.M{"$gte": 100, "$lte":1000}}
value := bson.M{query}
cur, _:= collection.Find(ctx, value)
fmt.Println{v}
```

i want to push or insert bson.M{} with value of variable query.

if i push with string in front like:  **bson.M{"selector": query}** code is working,

but i need push all value in variable query without string in the front.

can anyone help me? thank you

Comment: What do you mean by _"push all value in variable query without string in the front"_? You want to insert a document? You can't insert a document like `bson.M{"$gte": 100, "$lte":1000}`.

Comment: that right, i want to push that empty bson.M{} with another variable value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking to do?

```
query := map[string]interface{}{
    "number": bson.M{"$gte": 100, "$lte":1000},
}
cur, _:= collection.Find(ctx, query)
```